# Pyspark - Avg of Days by year and month

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, rdd, parquet

I have a CSV file stored in hdfs with the following format:

```
Business Line,Requisition (Job Title),Year,Month,Actual (# of Days)
Communications,1012_Com_Specialist,2017,February,150
Information Technology,5781_Programmer_Associate,2017,March,80
Information Technology,2497_Programmer_Senior,2017,March,120
Services,6871_Business_Analyst_Jr,2018,May,33
```

I would like to get the Average for Actual (# of Days) by Year and Month. Could someone please help me how I can do this using Pyspark and save the output in Parquet file?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert csv to DF and run spark-sql as below:

```
csvRDD.map(rec => {
 val i = rec.split(',');
 (i(0).toString, i(1).toString, i(2).toString, i(3).toString, i(4).toInt)   
}).toDF("businessline","jobtitle","year","month","actual").registerTempTable("input")

val resDF = sqlContext.sql("Select year, month, avg(actual) as avgactual from input group by year, month")
resDF.write.parquet("/user/path/solution1")
```